# Como mostrar los datos de un usuario logueado en java web

Tags: java, aplicación-web

hola necesito mostrar los datos del usuario logueado tengo en el servlet lo siguiente:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String user = request.getParameter("username");
    String pass = request.getParameter("password");

    Session Ss = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    Query rs = Ss.createQuery("From Trabajador where correo ='" + user + "'and contrasena='" + pass + "'");
    List<Trabajador> list = rs.list();

    for (Trabajador t :list) {

        if (t==t) {

            HttpSession newSession = request.getSession();
            newSession.setAttribute("usersession", user);
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");

        }else{

        response.getWriter().write("<script>alert('Usuario o contraseña incorrectos !');window.history.back();</script>");


        }   

    }
```

Loguea normal pero necesito mostrar los datos en un formulario para modificar pero al hacerlo solo puedo mostrar el correo y la contraseña con la que inicia
esta es la clase:

```
public class Trabajador  implements java.io.Serializable {

 private Integer idTrabajador;
 private Parqueadero parqueadero;
 private String nombres;
 private String apellidos;
 private String tipoDocumento;
 private String doumento;
 private String contrasena;
 private String correo;
 private String estado;

public Trabajador() {
}

public Trabajador(Parqueadero parqueadero, String nombres, String apellidos, String tipoDocumento, String doumento, String contrasena, String correo, String estado) {
   this.parqueadero = parqueadero;
   this.nombres = nombres;
   this.apellidos = apellidos;
   this.tipoDocumento = tipoDocumento;
   this.doumento = doumento;
   this.contrasena = contrasena;
   this.correo = correo;
   this.estado = estado;
}

public Integer getIdTrabajador() {
    return this.idTrabajador;
}

public void setIdTrabajador(Integer idTrabajador) {
    this.idTrabajador = idTrabajador;
}
public Parqueadero getParqueadero() {
    return this.parqueadero;
}

public void setParqueadero(Parqueadero parqueadero) {
    this.parqueadero = parqueadero;
}
public String getNombres() {
    return this.nombres;
}

public void setNombres(String nombres) {
    this.nombres = nombres;
}
public String getApellidos() {
    return this.apellidos;
}

public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
}
public String getTipoDocumento() {
    return this.tipoDocumento;
}

public void setTipoDocumento(String tipoDocumento) {
    this.tipoDocumento = tipoDocumento;
}
public String getDoumento() {
    return this.doumento;
}

public void setDoumento(String doumento) {
    this.doumento = doumento;
}
public String getContrasena() {
    return this.contrasena;
}

public void setContrasena(String contrasena) {
    this.contrasena = contrasena;
}
public String getCorreo() {
    return this.correo;
}

public void setCorreo(String correo) {
    this.correo = correo;
}
public String getEstado() {
    return this.estado;
}

public void setEstado(String estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo que veo es que te faltan las anotaciones en tu clase Entity.

Debes tener algo así:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Trabajador")
public class Trabajador {
    private Integer idTrabajador;
    private Parqueadero parqueadero;
    private String nombres;
    private String apellidos;
    private String tipoDocumento;
    private String doumento;
    private String contrasena;
    private String correo;
    private String estado;
}
```

Las anotaciones son la forma en que Hibernate puede trabajar y hacer el mapping de tu bean con el resultSet. Otra cosa importante a considerar es que el nombre de tus propiedades coincida con el nombre de tus propiedades en la tabla de otro modo te toca agregarle igual una anotación que le ayuda hacer el mapping con el correcto nombre de tu columna en la tabla. Ejemplo:

```
 @Column(name = "address_line1")
 private String addressLine1;
```

Donde la columna en tu tabla se "address_line1" pero en tu bean se llama addressLine1

Otra cosa igual que tu variable user que la guardas en sesión solo trae el parámetro del correo para iniciar sesión. deberías guardar en sesión el objeto que te retornó tu consulta.

```
newSession.setAttribute("usersession", t);
```

Y cuando estés en tu JSP(suponiendo estés ocupando JSP para renderizar en el navegador) haces un casting del objeto del tipo Trabajador

```
Trabajador userData = (Trabajador) session.getAttribute("usersession");
```

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo de tu query, trabajador sería el usuario, por lo tanto en ese objecto 't' debes tener los datos del usuario.

De la misma forma envías el mensaje de error podés mandar el html para generar el formulario con los datos del trabajador.